# Want to setup eloquent relationship among the three tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm on Laravel 8 with Jetstream - Livewire, want to setup eloquent relationship between three tables. That is Category, Sub-Category and Menu Item. 1 category has many sub-categories, whereas 1 sub-category has only 1 category. 1 sub-category has many menu items, whereas 1 menu item has only 1 sub-category. How should I proceed with the following, mainly with the above relationship I want to create CRUD functionality with all the three table in a single blade view, please guide me. Please check the table below.

```
Category Table
-----------------------
id
category_name

Sub Category Table
-----------------------
id
category_id
sub_category_name

Menu Item Table
-----------------------
id
sub_category_id
item_name
item_description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your current structure the relations would be like below

**Category Table**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fillable_values_here'
    ];

    public function subCategories() {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function menus() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'Menu::class',
            'SubCategory::class',
            'category_id',
            'sub_category_id'
        );
    }
}
```

**SubCategory Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fillable_values_here'
    ];

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function menus() {
        return $this->hasMany(Menu::class, 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

**Menu Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fillable_values_here'
    ];

    public function subCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class, 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

If you don't understand anything, feel free to ask. And read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) about Laravel relationship.

Comment: Thanks man this seems to work, I just need to give it a try, just needed to ask how should I form the migrations, I'm afraid, I am not much used to the migrations and assigning the foreign ids. If you can help me with it, it would be great! Thanks again. :)

Comment: make migration with model using command `php artisan make:model ModelName -m`. this will create both model and migration. and then add your column names in the migration file. and model code like i answered. complete migration reference can be found on [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations).

Comment: Thanks a lot bro this is working great! Its to the point. :)

Comment: Just one last thing, its displaying the sub categories along side the category in the CRUD database table. The whole CRUD table is in `@foreach` loop, how can I display the sub categories instead of `sub_category_id` in each row. As I'm using `@foreach` for the sub categories as well. So basically its `@foreach` loop inside another `@foreach` loop. The way I am doing it its just repeating all the sub category values. You've already helped me a lot, made my day. :)

Comment: Here is an image displaying the code: https://i.imgur.com/GcZYULz.jpg, and the output: https://i.imgur.com/PwAEkpS.jpg, Thanks already!

Comment: you want to show the menu items category name right?? you need not use any loop for this. just use relationship like `$menuitem->subCategory->sub_category_name`

Comment: Mate, it worked!!! Thanks a lot bro, I was trying this kind of stuff since 5 days now, really it means a lot.

Comment: go through the laravel doc. it will help you a lot. good luck.

Comment: Bro if you can assist me in this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64464614/13399106. I am unable to achieve the said output. Please have a look once, when you got time. Thanks already :)

Answer (score 1):

For `Category`: it's a one-to-many self-referencing relationship.

You don't need a separate table for sub-categories. It can easily be managed with a single `Category` table.

Your `Category` table schema can look like this:

```
id
category_title
category_id (default: null)
```

Where `category_id` is the parent of a certain category.

`category_id` is a foreign key to itself (category table). Hence self-refrencing relationship. By default it's set to null, meaning it's root parent element and has no parent.

Example:

```
id       category_title                category_id (or parent_id)

1        Welcome Drinks On Arrival       null
2        Essentials                       1
3        Mocktails                        1
```

Comment: `parent_category_id` would probably be a better name. Also, you don't want a default of `0` because the database will complain when the foreign key constraint isn't met. Default `null` would be better.

Comment: Actually I need the sub category for the function, I am creating a master menu for events, let say Category as `Welcome Drinks On Arrival` which has Sub-Categories as `Essentials`, `Mocktails`, `Fresh Fruit Juices` and under the sub-categories there are several Menu Items.