# Make parent as the option group header along with the children as the options - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a has many through eloquent relationship, between `Categories->SubCategories->MenuItems`. I need to display a category name as the optgroup header and its subcategories as the option value. Instead of my expectations, its showing the category above each and every sub-category. Sorry for being a noob, please help me.

Here's what I have done so far.

```
<select wire:model="sub_category_id" class="form-select block w-full mt-1">
    <option>Select Sub Category</option>
    @foreach ($menuitemlist as $menuitem)
        <optgroup label="{{ $menuitem->SubCategories->Categories->category_name }}">
            <option value="{{ $menuitem->SubCategories->id }}">{{ $menuitem->SubCategories->sub_category_name }}</option>
        </optgroup>
    @endforeach
    @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
</select>
```

This is the output which I am getting.
[image]

### Edit

Here are my relations.
Category Model

```
public function SubCategories() {
   return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id');
}

public function MenuItems() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(MenuItem::class, SubCategory::class, 'category_id', 'sub_category_id');
}
```

SubCategory Model

```
public function Categories() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}

public function MenuItems() {
    return $this->hasMany(MenuItem::class, 'sub_category_id');
}
```

MenuItem Model

```
public function SubCategories() {
    return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class, 'sub_category_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relations?

Comment: @iamab.in I have updated the question with the relations

Comment: how are you querying to get `$menuitemlist`??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Hey mate, actually I'm passing it to the view with pagination and search parameters `'menuitemlist' => MenuItem::where('item_name','like', $searchParams)->latest()->paginate(5)`. This is the above query, if that what you meant.

Comment: in this case for some menu the sub category may be the same. what will happen then?? you want to make two or more select option for the same sub category??

Comment: No, actually I want to display the `category_name` as the label of the option select with `<optgroup>` under that, I want to display the `sub_category_name` of the sub-categories, which falls under the same category. In short I need categorize sub-categories which belongs to the same category and group them under the `category_name` without repeating it.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with menu item. right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223415/discussion-between-toxifiedhashkey-and-zahid-hasan-emon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are actually trying to show all sub categories with category name as the option group header. your solution would be sending the categories from the component and then loop them to get sub categories.

in component

```
//don't forget to call Category Model
use App\Models\Category;
public function render()
{
    $searchParams = '%'.$this->search.'%';
    $menuitemlist = MenuItem::where('item_name','like', $searchParams)->latest()->paginate(5);
    $categories = Category::with('SubCategories')->get();

    return view('livewire.master-menu.menu-item-list', ['menuitemlist' => $menuitemlist, 'categories' => $categories]);
}
```

and then in view loop categories first and then the sub categories.

```
<select wire:model="sub_category_id" class="form-select block w-full mt-1">
    <option>Select Sub Category</option>
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
       <optgroup label="{{ $category->category_name }}">
           @foreach ($category->SubCategories as $sub)
               <option value="{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $sub->sub_category_name }}</option>
           @endforeach
       </optgroup>
    @endforeach
    @error('sub_category_id') <h1 class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</h1>@enderror
</select>
```

Comment: To the point bro. Exactly what I wanted and was expecting, thanks a lot. I owe you big time. :)

Comment: Hey Zahid, If you are available can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65874013/13399106, I seriously need help, If you could, I would be much grateful. Thanks for you time :)