# Unable to pass an array of selected data from parent component with traits to the nested component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

#### Application Structure

- App/Http/Livewire

1. UserController - Livewire/UserManagement/UserController
2. WithBulkActions - Livewire/Traits/DataTable/WithBulkActions

- resources/views/livewire

1. UserController Blade - livewire/user-management/user-controller

#### Description

I am creating a CRUD system, with bulk actions to delete the selected data. I have extracted the logic which is responsible to select multiple items or to select all items in the current data table i.e UserController, so I can use it as a trait i.e. WithBulkActions, in other data table components. The trait is only responsible to select multiple items or to select all items from the data table. The public function method to delete an array of data, is present in the data table component controller itself i.e. UserController. Now, to make the multiple select with bulk actions work, I have to include the confirmation modal, which is responsible to fire the method to delete an array of data, in the data table component blade view i.e. UserController Blade. It works perfectly when I include the confirmation modal to delete the selected data inside the user controller. While each row has a checkbox modeled to `wire:model="selected"` with the `value="{{ $user->id }}"` within the foreach loop. The public variable `selected` is initialized as `public $selected = [];` within the trait, WithBulkActions and then the trait is being used in the component, UserController.

`rowsQuery` property within the UserController component gets the data from the User model in a query with the filters, sorting and return it as a property.

```
public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = User::query()
            ->when($this->filters['email'], fn($query, $email) => $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query->whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->where('id', $role)))
            ->when($this->filters['search'], fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['date-min'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)))
            ->when($this->filters['date-max'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)));
        
        return $this->applySorting($query);
    }
```

Then the `rowsQuery` is cloned in the `selectedRowsQuery` property within the trait, WithBulkActions.

```
public function getSelectedRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        return (clone $this->rowsQuery)
            ->unless($this->selectAll, fn($query) => $query->whereKey($this->selected));
    }
```

If incase an array of data is being selected and the selected data should be deleted, the `public function confirmDeleteBulk()` is responsible for it, which is in UserController component, the following public function calls for `selectedRowsQuery` property, which is initialized in the trait itself, and then it executes the delete() method and notify accordingly.

```
public function confirmDeleteBulk()
    {
        $deleteCount = $this->selectedRowsQuery->count();
        foreach ($this->selectedRowsQuery->get() as $queryRow) {
            $queryRow->roles()->detach();
        }
        $this->selectedRowsQuery->delete();
        $this->showUserBulkDeletionModal = false;
        $this->notify('You\'ve deleted '.$deleteCount.' users');
    }
```

I tried making a separate livewire component with public function method to delete the selected data by displaying a confirmation modal but I was unable to pass the selected number of rows to the UserBulkDeletion nested component located at, Livewire/UserManagement/LogicalComponent/UserBulkDeletion. Please tell me the best use case in this situation, incase if what I want is possible. Help will be really appreciated, as I'm trying to do this since 2 weeks now.

**Context**

- Livewire version: 2.3.8
- Laravel version: 8.24.0
- Alpine version: 2.8.0
- Browser: Chrome

#### Edit

- Livewire/UserManagement/UserController

```
class UserController extends Component
{
    use WithCachedRows, WithSorting, WithBulkActions, WithPerPagePagination;

    public User $user;
    public $showFilters = false;
    public $filters = [
        'search' => "",
        'email' => null,
        'role' => '',
        'date-min' => null,
        'date-max' => null,
    ];

    protected $listeners = ['sectionRefresh' => '$refresh'];

    public function toggleShowFilters()
    {
        $this->useCachedRows();

        $this->showFilters = ! $this->showFilters;
    }

    public function resetFilters() 
    {
        $this->reset('filters'); 
    }

    public function updatedFilters() 
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }
    
    public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = User::query()
            ->when($this->filters['email'], fn($query, $email) => $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query->whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->where('id', $role)))
            ->when($this->filters['search'], fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['date-min'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)))
            ->when($this->filters['date-max'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)));
        
        return $this->applySorting($query);
    }

    public function getRowsProperty()
    {
        return $this->cache(function () {
            return $this->applyPagination($this->rowsQuery);
        });
    }

    public function getRolesProperty()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return $roles;
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.management.audience-management.user-controller', ['users' => $this->rows, 'roles' => $this->roles]);
    }
}
```

- Livewire/UserManagement/LogicalComponent/UserBulkDeletion

```
class UserBulkDeletion extends Component
{
    use WithCachedRows, WithBulkActions, WithSorting;
    
    public $showUserBulkDeletionModal = false;
    public User $user;
    public $filters = [
        'search' => "",
        'email' => null,
        'role' => '',
        'date-min' => null,
        'date-max' => null,
    ];

    protected $listeners = ['deleteUserBulk'];

    public function deleteUserBulk()
    {
        $this->useCachedRows();

        $this->showUserBulkDeletionModal = true;
    }

    public function confirmDeleteBulk()
    {
        $deleteCount = $this->selectedRowsQuery->count();
        
        foreach ($this->selectedRowsQuery->get() as $queryRow) {
            $queryRow->roles()->detach();
        }

        $this->selectedRowsQuery->delete();
        $this->showUserBulkDeletionModal = false;

        $this->notify('You\'ve deleted '.$deleteCount.' users');
        $this->emit('sectionRefresh');
    }

    public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = User::query()
            ->when($this->filters['email'], fn($query, $email) => $query->where('email', 'like', '%'.$email.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query->whereHas('roles', fn ($query) => $query->where('id', $role)))
            ->when($this->filters['search'], fn($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%'))
            ->when($this->filters['date-min'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)))
            ->when($this->filters['date-max'], fn($query, $created_at) => $query->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $created_at)));
        
        return $this->applySorting($query);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.backend.management.audience-management.logical-component.user-bulk-deletion');
    }
}
```

- Livewire/Traits/DataTable/WithBulkActions

```
trait WithBulkActions
{
    public $selectPage = false;
    public $selectAll = false;
    public $selected = [];

    public function renderingWithBulkActions()
    {
        if ($this->selectAll) $this->selectPageRows();
    }

    public function updatedSelected()
    {
        $this->selectAll = false;
        $this->selectPage = false;
    }

    public function updatedSelectPage($value)
    {
        if ($value) return $this->selectPageRows();

        $this->selectAll = false;
        $this->selected = [];
    }

    public function selectPageRows()
    {
        $this->selected = $this->rows->pluck('id')->map(fn($id) => (string) $id);
    }

    public function selectAll()
    {
        $this->selectAll = true;
    }

    public function getSelectedRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        return (clone $this->rowsQuery)
            ->unless($this->selectAll, fn($query) => $query->whereKey($this->selected));
    }
}
```

- views/livewire/user-management/logical-component/user-bulk-deletion

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="confirmDeleteBulk">
        <x-modal.confirmation wire:model.defer="showUserBulkDeletionModal">
            <x-slot name="title">Delete User</x-slot>

            <x-slot name="content">
                @json($selected)
                Are you sure you want to delete users? This action is irreversible!
            </x-slot>

            <x-slot name="footer">
                <x-button.secondary wire:click="$set('showUserBulkDeletionModal', false)">Cancel</x-button.primary>

                <x-button.primary type="submit">Delete</x-button.primary>
            </x-slot>
        </x-modal.confirmation>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from one Livewire component to another use [events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events).

> Livewire components can communicate with each other through a global event system. As long as two Livewire components are living on the same page, they can communicate using events and listeners.

In one of your Livewire components you trigger an event like

```
$this->event('usersToDelete', [ 1,2,3 ]);
```

In another component you can listen for this event

```
public class MyOtherComponent extends Component
{

    protected $listeners = [
      'usersToDelete' => 'deleteUsers'
    ];

    public function deleteUsers(array $user)
    {
      // .. do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to pass `$selected = []` which is initialized in traits, to the bulk deletion component. As whatever a user selects is stored in the variable `$selected` which is defined as an [ ]. I emit the following event `wire:click="$emit('deleteUserBulk')"` to show to bulk deletion component. How can I pass `$selected` along with `wire:click="$emit('deleteUserBulk')"`?

Comment: `wire:click="$emit('deleteUserBulk', $selected)"`... try this please. There is also a [Github issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/110) describing how to pass one/multiple parameter.

Comment: Why am I getting `$selected` not defined, as I have defined them in the trait WithBulkActions and I am using that trait in BulkDeletion component as well as in UserController component, so why its throwing this sort of error, `Uncaught ReferenceError: $selected is not defined` any clue?

Comment: Can you show the _complete_ Livewire components and your _complete_ trait in your original post?

Comment: Hey, have done that, sorry for the lengthy code 

Comment: Can you also please show the content of this view `livewire.backend.management.audience-management.logical-component.user-bulk-deletion`?

Comment: Yes surely, I'm using the same code as of jetstream modal component. I've updated my answer with the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227774/discussion-between-toxifiedhashkey-and-codedge).

Comment: Mate, you there?

Comment: make sure that $selected is define and can be accessed publicly anywhere in your component troubleshoot using dd($select) function then wire:click="$emit('deleteUserBulk', {{$selected}})" will work for you